# Reading context parameters from a POJO

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pojo

I have a parameter defined in my web.xml like

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>val</param-name>
    <param-value>SomeValue</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Is it possible to read it through a POJO in my webapp ? I dont want to use an XML parser

Answer (score 0):

Use the [getInitParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method from ServletContext

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("param-name");
```

Comment: getServletContext() is not available in a POJO. Do i need to extend the POJO by httpServlet ?

Comment: You how to get hold of the ServletContext somehow